# Friend Class to access the protected virtual function in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, virtual-functions, friend-class

I have three classes: `Class A`, `Class B` and `Class C`. `Class B` is `derived` from `Class A`. A `protected` pure `virtual function` declared in `class A` is defined in `Class B`. Class C is a `friend` function of Class A. Now I need to call that `virtual function` from class C. When I try to compile, I get the error as `cannot access protected member declared in class A`.

Isn't it possible?

Edit: Code added:

```
//A.h

class A
{
    friend class C;
 protected:
   virtual int SetPtr(unsigned long long Offset)=0;
};



//B.h
class B: public A
{
protected:
            int SetPtr(unsigned long long Offset) override;//function defined in B.cpp
};

//C.h

class C
{
public:
    C(A& aObj);
    int CallMyFun();
private:
    A& obj;
};

//C.cpp:

C::C(A& aObj) :obj(aObj)
{
}

int C::CallMyFun()
{
    obj.SetPtr(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is possible. Please show your code.

Comment: @songyuanyao: code added

Comment: Can't reproduce. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mH2mwvnVWPcjS4KS

Comment: @songyuanyao: I simplified the code.. A is in a namespace and C in another namespace. Also in different projects of Visual Studio solution. Does that matters

Comment: It should not matter, if the class `C` mentioned in the friend declaration is correct, might be something like `NS::C`. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/q6HwxpE2C0MswB3X